# gtk+/gtksourceview how to insert line-comment or block-comment

Tags: c, gtk, gtksourceview

I am creating a text editor in C using gtk+-2.0 gtksourceview-2.0.  I am having trouble finding any information about how to comment a line or a block. I am finding plenty of information about how to highlight these commented lines, but nothing about actually creating these comments.  I have searched google, devhelp, and the gedit and anjuta sources I use when I get stuck. No joy.

Do I need to write this functionality from scratch or are there any preexisting functions in gtksourceview that enable this functionality?  I don't mind writing it from scratch, it just seems like such basic functionality, and I didn't want to waste my time reinventing the wheel.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to, say, insert an empty comment block "/*\n*/" into the buffer?

Comment: @gcbenison No, I want to comment and uncomment existing code within the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function doesn't exist. See [this code](https://github.com/ptomato/gnome-inform7/blob/master/src/actions.c) for an example if you don't want to reinvent the wheel; look at the functions `action_comment_out_selection()` and `action_uncomment_selection()`.

Comment: Thanks again.  I think I will have a go at reinventing the wheel after all (I'm sure there is something to learn there), but I will use your example if I get stuck.